# Why is locationmanager returning old location fixes with new gettime-timestamp?

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

We have an app that upon user action tries to get a location fix. It listens both on GPS and network and has a time/accuracy based decision matrix to determine when to stop listening and what fix to return.

We have noticed, on occasion, a very strange behaviour. We use the classic way to see how old the fix is, like so:

```
long age = now - newLocation.getTime();
if(age >= prefs.getLocationMaxAge()){
    Log.d(TAG, "location too old.");
    return;
}
```

But sometimes, the location.getTime returned from the OS has an age of perhaps 15-20 seconds, according to the returned timestamp, although we can tell for certain that it's very old. For example, if the longitude/latitude fix is from a position that the handset was on 30 minutes ago!

It seems to happen both from Wi-Fi and network, but not GPS. To me, this is totally crazy. Has anyone else seen this and is there any way around it?

We have gotten it on a couple of different phones, most recent one is [Samsung Galaxy S II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II).

Help would be extremely welcome.

**EDIT**: To be really clear, the problem is that the "onlocationchanged" callback gets called by the OS with a location with a timestamp age of perhaps a couple of seconds, when I know for certain that the longitude/latitude in the "new" fix is a place where the phone hasn't been at for at least 30 minutes.

This makes it kind of hard to accurately determine where the handset it...

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to happen both from Wi-Fi and network, but not GPS

This seems fair, because in the Wi-Fi and network cell-site based triangulation, the accuracy is very bad. They are probably using cached locations which date back to 30 minutes ago. Unless you have not changed your cell-site or moved to another building so that new [APs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point) can be discovered, I'm afraid you will get only cached locations. If you want fresh locations use the GPS provider.

Comment: I think you are missing my point. Cached locations would be fine, if the timestamp of the location would reflect this. But taking a cached, old fix, and applying a current timestamp is crazy. i will update my question to be even clearer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up; I've found [the culprit](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/location/java/com/android/internal/location/LocationCollector.java)

Comment: HI guyz , relative to this i got location proper but when i try to find how old this location using ->> long age = System.currentTimeMillis() -location.getTime(); and depend on this value i calculate how my location is but the problem is sometime i got negative value (age). not able to understood why because that age will never comes in negative