# Disable or avoid fake gps

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app.

This program can detect fake positions.

But I want to avoid this problem by using Java programming.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect or prevent if user uses fake location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569245/detect-or-prevent-if-user-uses-fake-location)

Comment: This code does not work please explain more

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isMockLocation(Location location) {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 && location != null && location.isFromMockProvider();
}

//pass your location object here.
if(isMockLocation(location)){
//Restrict user
}elese{
//do whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: This code does not work

please explain more .

Comment: @MohammadaminNajafi You need to provide location object in this method and check isMocakLocation then you need to restrict user and in else part you do you code whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

The min API is 17 and the max is 29.

Does your code work?

Comment: @MohammadaminNajafi Change your min API to 18 it's works.